# Newly created Internal Network in Hyper-V is Undefined Network

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

I want to create a new network in Hyper-V manager with the following conditions:

> Subnet /24 (for example 192.168.21.0/24)

> The IP Address of each VM remains the same with DHCP with MacAddress checking (or I can set IP manually)

What I did:

1. I did create a new network, changed the IP in Windows Adapter Settings to the mentioned one and changed network of VM to new network.

Then I did `ping 1.1.1.1` and I had no internet.

2. I tried to change the subnet and IP of default switch, but I googled and found it's not possible to do so, so I decided to create a new network.
3. I changed the Mac Address settings of VM from Dynamic to Static, to see if `netplan apply` changes IP, which did change.

If matters, my VM OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

How to solve this issue?

**Update 1**

As @harrymc said in comments, these are the pictures:

**Switch config in Hyper-V:**

[image]

**The status of new network in Network Adapters:**

[image]

What I did is exactly like the default switch:

[image]

`ifconfig` output in the VM when I change the network and after I ran `netplan apply`:

[image]

Comment: Please include in your post the screenshots of the relevant Hyper-V configuration settings.

Comment: @harrymc I did edit the question.

Comment: Perhaps your problem is [this one](https://danielsmon.com/2016/11/08/windows-10-unidentified-network/). If it helps you, I'll put up an answer.

Comment: You'll need to set up NAT yourself. New internal switch does not come with that out of the box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network#create-a-nat-virtual-network (I am not sure if that implicitly enable IP forwarding as well or if that's always on for internal switches; if you want to avoid NAT just try to set up static (return) route for the prefix on your router)

Comment: Also AFAIK other than the "Default Switch" you don't get any builtin DHCP server from Hyper-V. So also set up static IP on the VM guest(s).

Comment: @harrymc I saw the link but it did not help me unfortunately.